# Why is String-String concatenation quicker than String-long concatenation?

Tags: java, concatenation, string-concatenation

In `Java`, the following code:

```
long x = 123;
String s = "abc" + x;
```

takes a significantly more runtime than:

```
long x = 123;
String s = "abc" + String.valueOf(x);
```

I got to know this through leetcode. I was trying to solve the following problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/fraction-to-recurring-decimal/

Here is the exact code for my solution:

```
public String fractionToDecimal(int numerator, int denominator) {
    long n = numerator, d = denominator;
    boolean isNegative = (n * d < 0);
    if(n < 0) n = -n;
    if(d < 0) d = -d;
    long q = n / d;
    long r = n % d;
    if(r == 0) return (isNegative ? "-" : "") + q;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if(isNegative) sb.append('-');
    sb.append(q).append('.');
    Map<Long, Integer> found = new HashMap<>();
    int index = sb.length();
    while(r > 0 && !found.containsKey(r)){
        found.put(r, index++);
        n = r * 10;
        q = n / d;
        r = n % d;
        sb.append(q);
    }
    if(r > 0) {
        sb.insert(found.get(r), "(");
        sb.append(')');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

When I click on `Submit` it takes as long as **7 milliseconds** to complete.
But if I literally just change line no. 8 from `+ q` to `+ String.valueOf(q)` the runtime plummets down to just **1 millisecond**. Please feel free to copy paste the code on leetcode to try it out there and see this change in runtime for yourself, if necessary.

This is highly confusing to me. Why is this happening? As per my understanding, in both the cases, compiler first converts the long to a String, and then concatenates those two Strings together, right? So, under the hood, isn't concatenating a String and a long exactly the same as concatenating two Strings together? Then why does one take more time to run than the other? Any insight would be highly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Where are your microbenchmark results which prove your assertion?

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion of significantly different timing? How did you measure, and what are your numbers? You know, proper benchmarking is hard in Java....

Comment: @f1sh: I'd take that bet in a nanosecond. The first doesn't involve any concatenation at execution time, the second does.

Comment: @JonSkeet I assumed that the compiler would know about `String.valueOf(123);` being a constant expression. But you win, take my money!

Comment: @f1sh No method calls are constant expressions in Java

Comment: I haven't done any benchmark tests. It's according to runtime on leetcode. Anyways, never mind, the question has been badly downvoted by now, so no use anymore.

Comment: You've now changed the question significantly so that my answer doesn't make any sense. Please don't do that.

Comment: @Jon: If on your machine the first approach was still more efficient than the second, then looks like this is more a leetcode issue than a Java issue. Cool, thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce your results on Leetcode either. Your solution shows as 0ms consistently for me. I've just tried introducing a loop so it actually evaluates the result 100,000 times before returning it... at that point it takes 25-50ms (inconsistent, and still not enough for a benchmark) but it *still* doesn't show the behavioyr you're describing.

Comment: I suggest AG: research how to do proper micro benchmarking with java. Then measure your code locally. Exclude anything that you can't control.

Comment: @JonSkeet
Using + q -> https://pasteboard.co/JoKOcQO.png ,
Using + String.valueOf(q) -> https://pasteboard.co/JoKPUQs.png

Comment: @GhostCat yeah looks like a leetcode problem indeed.

Comment: I wonder whether the "submit" behaves differently to "run" then - I was previously just using "run". Either way, to be honest anything that's running for a total of only a few milliseconds means that any extra method that only needs to be loaded in one case rather than the other can dwarf the cost of *executing* it.

Comment: That's right. "Run" means the code runs for just one testcase. "Submit" means the code is run on multiple testcases.

Answer (score 7):

Note: this answer was written before the question was changed. It used to include the expressions shown below.

`"abc" + 123` is a constant expression - the concatenation is done at *compile-time* so "abc123" ends up in the constant pool.

`"abc" + String.valueOf(123)` is *not* a constant expression. The concatenation happens at execution time, which is obviously rather more expensive than just using the compile-time concatenation result.

So I'd expect the result to be the *opposite* of what you've actually reported in the question.

Comment: Well, the OP claims the exact opposite of what Jon says. Albeit Jon's explanations are of course 100 correct.

Comment: @GhostCat: Oh well spotted - I hadn't noticed that. I wonder whether this is just a typo in the question.

Comment: but this is epic where the question got 6 downvotes while answer got 6 upvotes. if we liked the answer then possibly the question asked is also right.

Comment: @Hades: The question as originally asked would have made sense if they'd just been mixed up about which version was taking longer. With the change, it doesn't make as much sense.

Comment: Sorry, Jon and everyone else for the confusion in my question. I edited it into the correct code. int has been changed to long. And the value is not being added directly but through a variable now. Silly me thought these changes wouldn't matter, and so I unknowingly ended up making the code way more simpler than it needed to be, to the point that it changed the internal flow itself. Anyway, I've edited it, and reopened, so please feel free to help me out if possible, even though maybe you guys are too pissed off to care anymore. But please feel free to help out if possible. Sorry once again...